# Form validation using Codeigniter and JqueryUI dialog

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Just want to ask how can i have a form validation in a dialog box using jquery?
For example I have a button if you click the button a jquery will be called and that jquery will load my VIEW from another HTML. If the user submit with a duplicate username, the form validation must be in the same dialog box. In my case if the validation run, my page will go to the view of my form displaying the error message.

Here's my sample code:

**In my VIEW**

```
<input class="classname1"  type="button" value="ADD" name="add_category"/>
...
<div id="popup" style="display: none;"></div>
...
...
$(".hero-unit input[name=add_category]").on('click',function(){
        $('#popup').load("<?php echo site_url("category_controller/addCategoryItem/"); ?>").dialog({
            title: "Add New Category",
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 450,
            modal:true,
        });
    });
```

**In my controller**

```
public function addCategoryItem(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|is_unique[users.username]');
...
...
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $this->load->view('Category/contents/addNewItem');
}else{
    $this->cat_model->insertCat();
    echo "INSERTED";
}
}
```

**In my form VIEW**

```
echo form_open('category_controller/addCategoryItem');
?>
<input type='text' name='username' value='' />
<?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
<input type='submit' value='ADD' />
<?php
echo form_close();
```

Comment: use jquery validate.js plugin, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your form you should have an ajax call to submit the form.

I use ajaxForm. You can download the plugin for it here:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

And you need to include the whole form inside a div with an id, and target this div with ajaxForm.
Your form should also have an id.

For example:

```
<div id="ajaxResult">
<?php
$attr = array('id'=>'myForm');
echo form_open('url', $attr); ?>

Your form

</div>
<script>
$(function()
{
  var options = { target: '#ajaxResult' }; 
  $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);
});
</script>
```

That way, if there is an error, it will display it.